# Strong eta-rules for functions on sum types

Tags: type-theory, inductive-type, eta-equality

I am wondering whether a rule like the following is consistent with decidable conversion and type-checking for dependent type theory:

$$ \frac{f\, g : (x:\mathsf{bool}) \to C~x\quad f~\mathsf{tt} \equiv g~\mathsf{tt} \quad f~\mathsf{ff} \equiv g~\mathsf{ff}}{f\equiv g} $$

That is, if two functions with domain $\mathsf{bool}$ agree definitionally on $\mathsf{tt}$ and $\mathsf{ff}$, then they are convertible.  An analogous rule for functions on general inductive types like $\mathbb{N}$ is certainly bad, but it seems not *too* ridiculous to me to wonder whether the special case of $\mathsf{bool}$ (and other non-recursive inductive types, like sum-types and enumerated types) might be possible.

One thing that makes me somewhat hopeful is that this rule would make $(x:\mathsf{bool}) \to C~x$ behave very much like $C~\mathsf{tt} \times C~\mathsf{ff}$, and indeed be definitionally isomorphic to it if the latter also has an $\eta$-rule.  Since such a rule for products is possible, I thought maybe it could also be possible for the function-type.  And implementation-wise, I could imagine a bidirectional conversion-checking algorithm noticing when the type is a function with domain $\mathsf{bool}$ and deciding to apply this rule instead of the ordinary $\eta$-rule for functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we have $\eta$ for functions and also your pointwise conversion rule, that implies the full $\eta$ rule for the (finite) domain type. When checking conversion of arbitrary $t,u$, we can abstract over an arbitrary $\mathsf{bool}$ subterm $v$ to get an equivalent conversion problem

$$(\lambda~(x:\mathsf{bool}).~ t')~v\equiv(\lambda~(x:\mathsf{bool}).~ u')~v$$

For instance

$$\mathsf{if}~b~\mathsf{then}~t~\mathsf{else}~t \equiv (\lambda~x.~\mathsf{if}~x~\mathsf{then}~t~\mathsf{else}~t)~b \equiv (\lambda~x.t)~b \equiv t$$

The full $\eta$-rules for finite sums are rather complicated and expensive to check. There's a [reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01213) for STLC with finite sums and products. However, I do not know any reference for deciding finite sum $\eta$ in richer systems.

I expect that $\eta$ for *non-empty* finite sums remains decidable even in the fully dependent type theories. $\eta$ for the empty type is decidable only when consistency of typing contexts is decidable.

More specifically for our current case, let's assume that $\bot \to A$ is definitionally irrelevant. Then, if we have $p : \bot$ and $t,~u : A$, then

$$t \equiv (\lambda~x.~t)~p \equiv (\lambda~x.~u)~p \equiv u$$

Therefore, if $\bot$ is provable then all terms are convertible. This is undecidable for the usual $\bot$ in type theories, but it might be decidable  in other settings. For example, in [ABCFHL cubical type theory](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Syntax-and-models-of-Cartesian-cubical-type-theory-Angiuli-Brunerie/c4761e4aa77ff65e63fc60212d5e68461bae3a34) all judgments hold when the empty cofibration is implied by the context. This is still decidable because cofibrations are decidable. This is implemented in [cooltt](https://github.com/RedPRL/cooltt).

Alternatively, we can drop the function $\eta$ rule. Then, we recover the finite product types as $(x : A) \to C~x$ for finite $A$, and everything is decidable. I don't think this configuration is useful for anything though.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you say anything about why you expect $\eta$ for non-empty finite sums to still be decidable in dependent type theories?

Comment: I haven't looked deeply into this topic so I only have pretty naive intuition. My naive algorithm would be something like: for comparing $\beta$-normal $t$ and $u$, we pick a $\mathsf{Bool}$-typed neutral subterm, in either $t$ or $u$, then rewrite all occurrences of that subterm to $\mathsf{true}$ and $\mathsf{false}$ to get two sub-problems. We repeat until there are no neutral $\mathsf{Bool}$ subterms, then check conversion. I'd be glad to be told by experts if this doesn't work or is incomplete, though.

Comment: @AndrásKovács in order to be complete, I guess you would need to keep track of the true/false assignements for the boolean subterms and be able to check that your assignment is valid (in the sense that you didn't assign true and false to two subterms that turn up to be convertible, possibly up to some previous assignments).

Comment: @kyodralliam That's a good point. What about this refinement: at each step I pick a neutral Bool subterm which doesn't have any neutral Bool subterms. I *think* that this would ensure that assignments stay compatible.

Comment: Martin Baillon and Pierre-Marie Pédrot provided me with the following example of a "tricky" conversion problem: 
`α : ℕ →  ⊢ match α 42 as b return ∀ (n : ℕ), b = α n → ℕ with | true => 5 | false => 5 end 42 refl ≡ 5 : ℕ`
In that case, brutally rewriting the neutral subterm `α 42` with `true` and `false` yield terms that are not well-typed (because you lose the fact that `refl` has the adequate type unless you track the assignement in the conversion)

Comment: @kyodralliam Uhh, right. We can't simply rewrite neutrals. Then the algorithm must be indeed more complicated. I still have the intuition though that it should be decidable in dependent TTs.

Comment: A few months back, I almost wrote down a proof of decidability but I got distracted by more important tasks (to be very clear, I'm not claiming a proof yet). I would feel more inclined to work on it if I felt there were some practical application, or opportunity for a fun collaboration ;-)